# how to seperat field of one column in bash?

Tags: perl

I have the following tab-delimited file:

```
1 1 0 0 2 -9 BB A A B A B ...
2 2 0 0 2 -9 AA B B A B A ...
3 3 0 0 2 -9 AB B A B A B ...
```

As you can see, the genotypes in 7th column have not been separated. I need the following tab-delimited file:

```
1 1 0 0 2 -9 B B A A B A B ...
2 2 0 0 2 -9 A A B B A B A ...
3 3 0 0 2 -9 A B B A B A B ...
```

I tried the following command:

```
perl -ne '
   ($id, $tmp) = split( / /, $_, 2 );
   $tmp =~ s/ //g;
   print "$id ";
   print join(" ", split( //, $tmp ) );
' ped1 > ped2
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Just to be clear... the seventh column is always two characters and you want them split up with a tab between them, effectively adding a column to the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the answer to the question in my comment is yes, try this:

```
awk -v FS="\t" -v OFS="\t" '{ sub(/^./, "&\t", $7); print }' ped1 > ped2
```

Edit:

Perl version:

```
perl -F"\t" -lanE 'BEGIN { $, = "\t" } $F[6] =~ s/^(.)/$1\t/; say @F' ped1 > ped2
```

Comment: `BEGIN { $, = "\t" } say @F` is more clearly and more concisely written as `say join "\t", @F`

Comment: `s/^(.)/$1\t/` can be replaced with the more efficient and more concise `s/^.\K/\t/s`

Comment: @ikegami I really don't see a purpose or point to using join when printing a list in a one-liner when you can get the same result more cleanly by taking advantage of `$OFS` (Though, granted the plain variable is cryptic, but I'm not going to use English in a one-liner). In a bigger program it *might* be different, depending on many things.

Comment: Using global variables to affect a different part of the program is the very definition of *less* clean.